# Firebase limit the number of records a user can save

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have a commenting system but I don't want more than 10 comments from the same user on a blog post. How would I do that based on the following data schema:

```
0:
    user_id: 1
    comment: Some comment

1:
    user_id: 1
    comment: Some other comment same user
```

I know I'm supposed to tweak the security rules but I can't seem to find out a way of limit a user to not post more than 10 comments per post or per total for that matter.

Any example of such rules?

Comment: I think you would need to keep track of a user's number of comments per post somewhere in your Firebase tree, and then reference that number in your security rules. Does this make sense? You could require that the client increment that number when making a post.

Comment: I know what you're saying but whats stopping the client from not incrementing it or even decrementing it? This is a limitation and I don't think the client should have anything to say about it.

Comment: Hmm. That's a good point. I think you could stop someone from decrementing the count with a security rule comparing the old value to the new value, but I'm not sure how you could force them to increment it. I was also thinking that a RulesDataSnapshot would have a numChildren() method, but it doesn't seem to. You might need a node server that counts changes for you. Soon someone from Firebase will probably answer you definitively though.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Having a nodejs server in the background counting things kinda defeats the whole purpose of using firebase because my client would need to check with the server before submitting the data so I double my requests. I already back my application with node but I was really hoping to not need it at this early stage. Those rules are the only thing stopping unwanted data and it needs to be able to handle such tasks otherwise parse's cloud code might seem better. I'll wait for an answer from firebase though.

Comment: Well, you could still do it without your client directly communicating with your server. Your server would just increment the count variable, and you're client would be bound by security rules based on that count variable. I guess there's a chance someone would run a script to submit many postings extremely quickly, before the server could update the count, but you could have the server immediately clean those up.

Comment: Meh I switched to sails. I like the idea behind but still not very convinced. Thank you for the help though.